# Source of Godel's quote on materialism

Tags: materialism, goedel

[In an interview](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VIgHsm3Faio), David Berlinski quoted Godel's view on materialism:

> It [materialism] succeeds to the extent that the materialists assign
>   material objects all the properties that used to be assigned to
>   non-material objects.

My Google search came up empty as to the source. It is possible that Berlinski reworded what Godel said. Can anybody confirm this quote with a source?

[The relevant section starts at 3:20.]

Comment: Maybe you have to search into [Hao Wang's works regarding discussions with Godel](https://www.google.com/search?q=hao+wang+godel&rlz=1C1GCEB_enIT849IT849&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjYqdGrqbnkAhXH_aQKHe6vBZMQ_AUIGCgB&biw=1366&bih=625).

Comment: Although Godel's dim view of materialism is well-known, nothing like this appears in the usual [quote repositories](http://kevincarmody.com/math/goedel.html). Berlinski likely confused Godel with someone else, that materialism endows matter with divine attributes was a common complaint of idealists since Marx, at least. If Godel did utter something like that, he was merely repeating it.